# Understanding $\zeta(s)$ is Holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, zeta-functions

I am trying to parse out the below paragraph [(click here and go to page 1)](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2018fa/LectureNotes16.pdf), it is written in Definition 16.1. that-

> It is easy to verify that this series converges absolutely and locally
>   uniformly on $Re(s) > 1$ (use the integral test on an open ball
>   strictly to the right of the line $Re(s) = 1$). By Theorem 16.17, it
>   defines a holomorphic function on Re(s) > 1, since each term $e^{-s
> \log n}$ is holomorphic.

Theorem 16.17 states that-

> Theorem 16.17. A sequence or series of holomorphic functions $f_n$
>   that converges locally uniformly on an open set $U$ converges to a
>   holomorphic function $f$ on $U$, and the sequence or series of
>   derivatives $f'_n$ then converges locally uniformly to $f'$ (and if
>   none of the $f_n$ has a zero in $U$ and $f \neq 0$, then $f$ has no
>   zeros in $U$).

What I understood is -

Point 1. Each term of $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphice since $n^{-s} = e^{-s \log n}$ and $e^{-s \log n}$ is holomorphic as $e^{-s \log n}$ is differentiable (we know $\frac{{{d}{\left({e}^{x}\right)}}}{{{\left.{d}{x}\right.}}}={e}^{x}$)

Point 2. $\zeta(s)$ converges (absolutely and locally uniformly) on $Re(s) > 1$ we can see this by  the integral test (on an open ball  strictly to the right of the line $Re(s) = 1$???)

Point 3. Finally we deduce that $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic since it satisfies two conditions as written above (Point 1, 2) of Theorem 16.17.

Is this understanding is correct? Is  the final result of the quoted paragraph is that $\zeta(s)$ is holomorphic ?

PS: it is not clear why the author wrote about "absolutely and locally uniformly" I learned about the integral test here, [( see Section 4-6 : Integral Test)](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx), there is no mention of absolutely or locally uniformly, can anyone comment on that (no answer is required)?

Comment: The integral test is a test of positive, real series, with decreasing coefficients, not of functions series, so naturally, any introduction will not mention concepts from convergence of sequences of functions. The point is that $\sum_{n=1} |n^{-s}|=\sum_{n=1} n^{-\Re s}$ and on the set $\{\Re s>1+\varepsilon\},$ we have that $n^{-\Re s}\leq n^{-(1+\varepsilon)}$, and the latter terms form a series that you can apply the integral test to. But yes: You have the right idea of the argument.

Comment: Yes but you are missing the main point :  there is a theorem stating that if $f_n$ is a sequence of analytic functions which converges locally uniformly then the limit $f$ is analytic. By the holomorphic $\implies$ analytic theorem it suffices to check that the $f_n$ are holomorphic. Those theorems follow from the **Cauchy integral formula**. You can't prove those theorems just in a few lines, you need to follow some complex analysis books (even if you don't need those deep theorems just to prove the analyticity of $\zeta(s)$)

Comment: @reuns 1. "There is a theorem stating that if $f_n$ is a sequence of analytic functions which converges locally uniformly then the limit $f$ is analytic."
- This Theorem 16.17 in the document, right?
2. "By the holomorphic ⟹ analytic theorem, it suffices to check that the $f_n$ is holomorphic."
- To show, the series of $f_n$ converges to a holomorphic function, right?
3. "Those theorems follow from the Cauchy integral formula." 
- You mean Theorem 16.17 follow from the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: @reuns 4. "Yes but you are missing the main point"
- Isn't holomorhicity of $\zeta(s)$ function main point in the paragraph mentioned?
At least respond by saying yes or no, if you don't want to go in detail.  the problem is , I can not start from the beginning, I did my complex analysis course many times ago, now I need specific and elaborate lecture notes or some specific chapters of well written book for beginner, which I could not find, could you suggest any.

Comment: I don't have any book recommandation, it depends on your level and taste and if you can find and check the relevant examples yourself. $f_n$ analytic implies $2i\pi f_n(z)  = \int_{|s-a|=R} \frac{f_n(s)}{s-z}ds$, if $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $|z-a|\le R$ then $2i\pi f(z)  = \int_{|s-a|=R} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$, expanding $\frac1{1-z/s}$ in geometric series implies that $f$ is analytic  on $|z-a|<R$ (and represented by its Taylor series at $a$).